# ¿ Como puedo Insertar elementos en una lista dinámica e imprimirlos?

Tags: c, lista, punteros, insertar

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de C en el que tengo crear una lista dinámica de estructuras a modo de base datos. El contenido de cada estructura se extrae de un fichero y se inserta como un nuevo nodo en la lista. El fichero puede contener varias estructuras consecutivas. He creado varias funciones: una para leer las estructuras desde el fichero (que funciona bien porque la he comprobado en etapas previas del proyecto), otra para crear los nodos de la lista con el contenido de cada estructura leída y otra para insertarlos en la lista. El código compila sin errores pero solo funciona bien cuando el fichero leído solo contiene una estructura. Cuando contiene más de una estructura pasa algo mal y al imprimmir la lista no sale lo que debería. He cambiado los parámetros que le paso a las funciones varias veces pero aún así no he conseguido arreglarlo. Agradecería enormemente que alguien me ayudara.

A continuación el código:

La definición de la estructuras está en un fichero ".h" que luego incluyo en el correspondiente ".c"

```
// estructura que representa los datos de una celda

    typedef struct network_st{
    
        unsigned int celda;
        char mac[SIZE]; 
        char essid[SIZE];
        enum modo mode;
        unsigned int canal;
        enum cifrado key;
        char calidad[5];
    
    }network_st;
    
    network_st *redes;
    
    typedef struct nodo_red{
    
        network_st red;
        struct nodo_red *prox;
    }nodo_red;
```

A continuación el código del fichero ".c" mencionado en el que se definen las funciones que

```
 int nodescounter = 0;
    
    nodo_red *lista = NULL;
    nodo_red *head=NULL;
       
    nodo_red* create_node(network_st red) {
            nodo_red *node = (nodo_red*) malloc(sizeof(nodo_red));
            node -> red = red;
            node -> prox = NULL;
            return node;
    }
    
    void insertar (nodo_red **head_ref, nodo_red *new_node) {
    
        nodo_red *last = *head_ref;
        if (*head_ref == NULL){
            *head_ref = new_node;
            return;
        }
        while (last->prox != NULL){
            last = last->prox;        
        }
        last->prox = new_node;
        return;
    }
    
    // inserta la info de cada celda (estructura) en la variable que se "convertira" en nodo de la lista
    
    void insert_new_cell(unsigned int celda, char mac[SIZE], 
        char essid [SIZE], enum modo mode, unsigned int canal,
        enum cifrado key, char calidad[5]) {
    
            redes->celda = celda;
            strcpy(redes->mac, mac);
            strcpy(redes->essid, essid);
            redes->mode = mode;
            redes->canal = canal;
            redes->key = key;
            strcpy(redes->calidad, calidad);
    
    nodo_red* nodo = NULL;
    nodo = create_node(* redes);
    if (nodescounter == 0) {
        head= nodo;
    }
    insertar(&lista, nodo);
    
    nodescounter++;
    
    redes = (network_st*) realloc (redes, (1+nodescounter)*sizeof(redes));
    
            }
    
        
    // funcion que muestra en pantalla los datos de las celdas 
    
    void imprimirceldas (nodo_red* tmphead){
    
    do {
        printf("\nCelda: %d\n", redes->celda);
        printf("MAC: %s\n", redes->mac);
        printf("ESSID: %s\n", redes->essid);
        switch (redes->mode) {
            
            case 0:
            printf("Modo: Auto\n");
            break;
                
            case 1:
            printf("Modo: Ad-Hoc\n");
            break;
    
            case 2:
            printf("Modo: Managed\n");
            break;
    
            case 3:
            printf("Modo: Master\n");
            break;
    
            case 4:
            printf("Modo: Repeater\n");
            break;
    
            case 5:
            printf("Modo: Secondary\n");
            break;
    
            case 6:
            printf("Modo: Monitor\n");
            break;
    
            default:
            printf("Modo: Unknow\n");
    
            } 
        printf("Canal: %d\n", redes->canal);
        switch (redes->key) {
            
            case 0:
            printf("Encriptacion: on\n");
            break;
                
            default:
            printf("Encriptacion: off\n");
        }
        printf("Calidad: %s\n\n", redes->calidad);
    
        tmphead = tmphead -> prox;
        
    }while (tmphead != NULL);
    }
```

Esta es la declaracion de la funcion que inserta la estructura en la lista

insert_new_cell(celda, ntmpmac, ntmpessid, mode, canal, key, ntmpcalidad);

Este es la definición de la función que imprime todos los elementos:

```
void displayall () {
    
        imprimirceldas(head);

}
```

Esta es su declaración:

```
 displayall();
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa y leo un fichero que tiene una sola estructura imprime el contenido de la lista que en este caso contiene un solo nodo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el programa y leo dos veces un fichero con una sola estructura, al imprimir la lista completa se imprimen los dos nodos iguales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el programa y leo un fichero que contiene mas de una estructura, no se que pasa que al imprimir la lista si bien sale el numero de nodos esperados, no sale el contenido de los mismos correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que se te imprime varias veces el último de los nodos. Por favor, comparte el código en que se ve cómo llamas a las funciones que muestras.

Comment: Acabo de agregar las partes de código en que declaro a las funciones definidas inicialmente. No he puesto el código completo porque es bastante largo y el resto no aporta nada al problema (creo), pero si fuera necesario lo compartiría también.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba equivocado [en mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/572718/como-puedo-insertar-elementos-en-una-lista-din%c3%a1mica-e-imprimirlos?noredirect=1#comment1013003_572718), no es que se te imprima varias veces el último nodo, es que todos los nodos contienen el mismo dato.

#### Problema.

Por algún motivo que no entiendo tienes un puntero a `network_st` que asumo que en algún punto inicializas ya que de lo contrario lo usas sin inicializar:

```
void insert_new_cell( ... ) {

//  vvvvv <--- usar el puntero redes presuntamente inicializado en otro punto
    redes->celda = celda;
    strcpy(redes->mac, mac);
    strcpy(redes->essid, essid);
    redes->mode = mode;
    redes->canal = canal;
    redes->key = key;
    strcpy(redes->calidad, calidad);
```

Ese puntero a `network_st` lo usas para crear un nuevo nodo pasando el `network_st` **por copia**:

```
nodo_red* create_node(network_st red) {
//    red se pasa por copia ---> ^^^
    nodo_red *node = (nodo_red*) malloc(sizeof(nodo_red));
    node -> red = red;
    node -> prox = NULL;
    return node;
}

void insert_new_cell( ... ) {
    ...

    nodo_red* nodo = NULL;
//                          /---- Pasamos a create_node el contenido de 'redes',
//                       vvvvv    copiando su contenido
    nodo = create_node(* redes);
    if (nodescounter == 0) {
        head= nodo;
    }
    insertar(&lista, nodo);

    ...
}
```

Finalmente realojas la memoria de `redes` pidiendo espacio para un puntero a `network_st` adicional:

```
nodescounter++;

redes = (network_st*) realloc (redes, (1+nodescounter)*sizeof(redes));
```

Esto es erróneo por dos motivos:

1. Si quieres espacio para otro `network_st` el tamaño que debes pedir es `(1+nodescounter)*sizeof(network_st)`<sup>1</sup>, con la instrucción `realloc` que has escrito estás pidiendo espacio para un **puntero a `network_st`**.
2. La memoria realojada crece en orden de lectura, los nuevos datos estarán a la derecha de los anteriores, por lo que en la primera posición siempre tendrás el primer dato que alojaste; en otras palabras: siempre estás escribiendo en el primer `network_st` y dejas el resto intactos.

#### Solución.

Sigue los siguientes consejos:

1. No uses variables globales.
2. No uses memoria dinámica (`malloc`/`realloc`) sin necesidad.
3. No uses los mismos tipos para cosas distintas, un nodo y una lista son cosas distintas.

Siguiendo esos consejos, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
typedef struct network_st{
    unsigned int celda;
} network_st;

typedef struct nodo_red{
    network_st red;
    struct nodo_red *prox;
} nodo_red;

// La lista contiene el nodo cabeza y el contador de nodos.
typedef struct lista{
    nodo_red *head;
    int nodescounter;
} lista;
    
nodo_red *create_node(network_st red) {
    nodo_red *node = (nodo_red*)malloc(sizeof(nodo_red));
    node -> red = red;
    node -> prox = NULL;
    return node;
}

// Al insertar le decimos en que lista lo queremos insertar.
void insertar(lista *l, nodo_red *new_node) {

    if (l->head == NULL){
        l->head = new_node;
        return;
    }

    nodo_red *last;

    // El cuerpo del for esta vacio ...
    // Solo usamos el for para avanzar el puntero ---> v
    for (last = l->head; last->prox; last = last->prox);

    last->prox = new_node;
}

// Al insertar celda le decimos en que lista la queremos insertar.
void insert_new_cell(lista *l, unsigned int celda) {

    network_st redes;
    redes.celda = celda;

    insertar(l, create_node(redes));
    ++l->nodescounter;
}

// Al imprimir le decimos de que lista lo queremos imprimir.
void imprimirceldas(lista *l){

    for (nodo_red *n = l->head; n; n = n->prox)
        printf("Celda: %d\n", n->red.celda);
}

int main(void)
{
    lista lista1, lista2;

    lista1.head = NULL;
    lista1.nodescounter = 0;
    lista2.head = NULL;
    lista2.nodescounter = 0;

    insert_new_cell(&lista1, 0);
    insert_new_cell(&lista2, 1);
    insert_new_cell(&lista1, 2);
    insert_new_cell(&lista2, 3);
    insert_new_cell(&lista1, 4);

    printf("La lista 1, contiene %d nodos:\n", lista1.nodescounter);
    imprimirceldas(&lista1);
    printf("La lista 2, contiene %d nodos:\n", lista2.nodescounter);
    imprimirceldas(&lista2);

    return 0;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que he simplificado la estructura `network_st` por comodidad. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNNj9owED3jXzHaqlXCBrSkPW26XHpFvfVWCaWOs2s12Mh2um0Rv52Ov4ITWNQIAX4z8/zmzYQunik9veOCdn3D4LM2DZfLlzUZQR3/gdjJ/NmzhrWgjeqpAcHMq1Q/t9ocCODTC82fBWuACwOUdU1dkWOSVREyZZCN3CrW@PpzJiBWOWySCPO9kr8dbUAuSTuuTR0Yh7IXVgdGKw5xpqnshWHKkrkSHybnGqpYbdjWJmdjbTlM@W0SPEEWkXm@q7tO0kzzv0y2A57nVaxksFhbMiwb2o2w7RLxr982Gx9QzPRKuDgK9kp/SW691kyZWmWuB5h3RaqKvTr5Vq9vvoWsW6ytG/Dk@XPfin2GCMTCaoh5Af58JJPuu9pN14KtVHgFnpEl8FVgz4u1Gx3E2ADlofKMjATgZUmjWxvA3eqSfi/3buh3PDamo5n4d@ky8aqwqWE5opsFpON3FXF29/fY2GSF0ons9orvuHK8etCZHxKDkhGlPgn82OaDMYP5SChMm919sZSP8L75Lu4Km4YUvo/cGWUN2NVcZFZITg5k5m9336vC/5bYq8dXyzBuv2cRTFvD4EOMlNfSyyvpZDYd1oeo4AGFvhEtC1i9HcXa8mbtx5u1n@yWzaKPm2AJYIRKYTgTDF11G60fnblXvHAXjIcb@G3kgru8zV3@H3fphIfXH709nk7/AA)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>O alternativamente `(1+nodescounter)*sizeof(*redes)`.

Answer (score 0):

En `void insert_new_cell()` tu escribes los nuevos valores al principio de `*redes`.
Luego tu creas un nuevo nodo, copias el contenido de `*redes` dentro y encadenas este nuevo nodo (`lista` tendrá siempre el mismo valor que `head`).

A nivel del `nodescounter++;` todo bien, los datos están en la lista bien encadenados.

Luego tu haces el área apuntada por `redes` más grande.
¿Porqué? No sirve de nada, ya que siempre escribes al principio.
Si tu creas una lista, no necesitas una tabla (*array*), es redundante; y `realloc()` sirve para alocar espacio para una tabla de dimensión variable.

Pero el error está más adelante: para imprimir, tu miras... al contenido de `*redes`; es decir, a los últimos valores entrados.
Tienes que mirar por la lista, es decir primero `lista->red` (`head->red`, es igual) y luego pasearte por la lista (`nodo = nodo->prox;`).